# How to add all the numbers together in some lists, in python

Tags: python, list

x=[1,2,5]
y=[2,3,9]
how can I get the result 22?

my code has type error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want the built-in `sum` function.

```
>>> x = [1,2,5]
>>> y = [2,3,9]
>>> sum(x+y)
22
```

This is the same thing as:

```
sum(x) + sum(y)
```

or if you love itertools:

```
sum(itertools.chain(x,y))
```

with the latter 2 being more efficient.

---

`sum` takes an iterable and sums all of it's elements.  when dealing with lists `+` concatenates, so:

```
x+y
```

gives you the list:

```
[1,2,5,2,3,9]
```

which is iterable and therefore a perfect candidate for `sum`.

---

If you have a whole bunch of lists you could make this even more interesting:

```
>>> lists = [x,y]
>>> sum(sum(lst) for lst in lists)
22
```

This last form is nice because it scales trivially up to an arbitrary number of lists -- just keep appending them to the `lists` list until you're ready to sum, pop that 1-liner in there and then you're done.

Of course, I suppose we could do the same thing with itertools as well:

```
sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists))
```

As you can see, you have quite a few options to play with (and learn from! :).

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid the array concatenation, `sum(x) + sum(y)`

Comment: @Xymostech -- or even `sum(sum(lst) for lst in (x,y))` :)

Comment: Well let's not get crazy now... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,5]

>>> list2 = [2,3,9]

>>> zip_list = [(x + y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]

>> zip_list

[3, 5, 14]

>>> sum(zip_list)

22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    sm=0
    for v in x+y:
         sm=sm+v
```